# ASP.NET link to open image in new page

Tags: html, asp.net, hyperlink

I have these two hyperlinks below.  The first one opens the actual image on the current page.   The second one creates a link called Image2, but when I click on it, the image on that new page does not show up.  I would really like the second one to open the image in a new page when the link is clicked on.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="id1" runat="server" target="_blank" ImageUrl='<%#"data:Image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ByteArrayFromDB")) %>' >Image1</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:HyperLink id="id2" runat="server" target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "data:Image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ByteArrayFromDB")) %>'>Image2</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Look at the final HTML markup (view source) and see what you get for the urls. I just tried it and my first link does nothing, and my 2nd link opened the image in a new tab. I just used a normal image though.

Comment: Well, if you want another page to open, then you have to navigate to that new page first, and then have it display the image. Or maybe you want the image to display in some sort of popup? So, if you want to move/jump/navigate to a new web page, then you should just get the users selection, and then based on the selection, pass that image ID or whatever to the next web page. But, you not going to get a whole new page to appear unless you make that new page in the first place. I mean, maybe a GridView, or listview to display all the choices - you then click on a row, and then display that image?